# How to avoid Generic DTO objects in .NET MVC, Is there a ExpandoObject solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop

I am using a GenericDTO object to pass information between my methods. Normally it includes a true/false value, a list of errors if any, and maybe something else miscellaneous.

The GenericDTO object has some generic properties such as `"string1","string2","boolean1","boolean2"`.

**It is not ideal.** *(But I don't want millions of DTO types, just for passing between methods).*

What is a better way to do this? I'd like to pass an object back. Is there a way to use the dynamic ASP.NET MVC objects ( like ViewBag ) to use them as DTO objects? Sure, no compile time checking... but it would be nice to avoid the Generic object scenario.

Comment: "Millions" of DTO's?  I think there is something fundamentally wrong with your design if it requires millions of different objects.  It sounds like you just want to serialize data and deserialize it.  Actually, it sounds more like an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you have convinced yourself that you have to use a terrible solution, when in reality you should be asking about the objectives of what you want to achieve. Your problem is not "how do I avoid DTO objects" it's "How do I pass data from one object to another given this situation

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question that defines the actual problem you are trying to solve, and asking for help with it.  Not asking for help with the terrible solution to your problem that you came up with.

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern is to have an object with a dictionary from strings to objects. The dictionary acts as a bag for anyhting, maps columns to values. Since dictionaries serialize fine with the DataContractSerializer, this is a reasonable alternative for a dto.

However, I am concerned by your "pass information between methods" as this is not what the DTO is for.

Comment: Yes I'm using DTO's for many applications in the Site, ajax etc, but have been using them between methods. If one wants to return more than one item from a method, what is the normal approach for this?

Comment: Normally you create a class with required properties.